# Keep Matplotlib barplot from resizing in PdfPages

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pdf-generation, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bunch of barplots in a loop and to save them all into a single PDF file. The issue is that depending on the data, the x axis can have different lengths. As a result, the barplots are all resized differently in the PDF document. I'd like the bars (and the space in between) to remain constant and to not appear resized in the PDF document. I've tried different combinations of parameters like setting `fig.figsize` or `bbox_tight`, but it didn't produce the desired result.

Here are two example images:
[image]
[image]

I'd like the x axis to resize according to the number of labels / data points, sothat the bars (and the space between the bars) are always the same size between different figures.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

outputs={"A":np.array([1.0,0]),"B":np.array([0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0]),"C":np.array([1,0.8,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.9,1.0,0.8])}

pp=PdfPages("barplots.pdf")
fig=plt.figure()
for name,array in outputs.items():

    x=[i for i in range(len(array))]
    labels=["{}".format(i) for i in x]
    plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(len(array),1))
    plt.ylim(0,1.1)

    plt.bar(x,array,width=0.2,tick_label=labels) ## if width is set lower, spacing between bars becomes quite large

    fig.savefig(pp,format="pdf",dpi=100)
    fig.clf()
pp.close()
```

Comment: Can you describe more in detail the desired output? Do you want to shrink the axes? Do you want to have additional whitespace inside the axes?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191668/matplotlib-dynamic-bar-chart-height-based-on-data). Instead of subplots you would create the axes in different figures. Of course you will need to decide about what the free parameter should be (figure size at constant bar width, or bar width at constant figure size).