# How to fix overlapping matplotlib y-axis tick labels or autoscale the plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am struggling to display my matplotlib barplot properly. When there are many y-axis tick labels (>100) the figure does not autoscale and the labels end up on top of one another.
On the other hand when there are few y-axis tick labels the figure looks zoomed in and the bar height is increased.

Is there a way to display a 'responsive' plot in its full size so that the figure size increases when necessary but the bar height remains the same regardless of how many y-axis data points there are?

Increasing `figsize` helps remove the overlapping but then the figure looks extremely large when there are fewer y tick labels.

This is the plot with overlapping labels:

[image: Plot with overlapping labels]

And here is one with fewer y labels:

[image: Plot with fewer labels]

```
label=[]
score_list=[]


index = np.arange(len(label))

#Plot resolution.
plt.figure(dpi=300)

#Plot a horizontal barplot.
plt.barh(index, score_list)

plt.ylabel('Kinase', fontsize=6)
plt.xlabel('z-score', fontsize=6)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=5)
plt.yticks(index, label, fontsize=4)

# Plot is further styled below.
ax=plt.gca()
for pos in ['right','top', 'left']:
    ax.spines[pos].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(left=False)
ax.set_xlim([mini, maxi])
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.15,0.5)
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,-0.15)

#Save plot.
plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: The idea would be to set the figure size as a function of the number of bars. I think similar quesitions have been asked and answered already on SO.

Comment: Also check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191668/matplotlib-dynamic-bar-chart-height-based-on-data/42192931#42192931) for the same with subplots.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will look into this now