# The labels on the x-axis are overlapping

Tags: matplotlib, random-forest

## Make a bar chart

`plt.bar(x_values,importances,orientation = 'vertical')`

## Tick labels for x axis

`plt.xticks(x_values,feature_list, rotation='vertical')`

## Axis labels and title

`plt.ylabel('Importance'); plt.xlabel('Variable'); plt.title('Variable Importances');`

## Output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Too many features for that size. You can resize the window or plot using more DPI or another figure size.

Comment: Or spread across two subplots, maybe sort by size and use different y scales for them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347378/how-to-fix-overlapping-matplotlib-y-axis-tick-labels-or-autoscale-the-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your help. I want to plot top 10 features. The rest can be ignored. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column

Comment: you might need numpy.argsort as you have to sort the features array and then apply the same sorting on the names. Maybe it is easier for you to use Pandas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html